# Probability Rule of Sum vs Rule of Product

Tags: probability

I m little bit confused on when to use Rule of Sum and when to use Rule of Product. Currently my understanding is this:

1. if you are using only one item (a die e.g.)  then use Rule of Sum.
2. if you are using more than one item (2 or more dice e.g.) then use Rule of Product.

What if replace the die with a deck of cards. Will above understanding still apply for 2 or more deck of cards ?

Am I correct in my reasoning ? Am I missing something  ?

Comment: These kinds of rules may be useful for answering elementary test questions of extremely limited scope, but learning how to think about probability it is far better to learn how to use the [axioms of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Axioms).  One reason to be wary is that "using only" and "using more than" are not well-defined concepts.

Comment: @whuber Seems like a good point. I will appreciate on some advice on "learning how to think about probability". Don't put it comment. Put it as reply to my question so that I can choose it as answer :)

Comment: "How to learn to think about probability" is a great question but it's far too broad to be addressed on this site.

Comment: Well, you got a blog ? or you can give me some pointers  ?